# Fiware Orion: Discover attributes in httpCustom notifications

Tags: fiware-orion

Orion allows use to create subscriptions with a template payload:

```
subject: {
    entities: [{ idPattern: "*"}]
}
httpCustom: {
    payload: "The temperature is ${temperature} degrees"
}
```

But since I can create a subscription on a pattern of sensors,
I don't necessarily knows the attributes names in the payload... How could I discover them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the attribute names in order to include them using macros, e.g. `${temperature}`.

Note that customization notification is designed as an easy to use mechanism to do simple substitutions (but yet powerfull to cover many third-party integration cases), not a full fledged template language including loops, associative maps, etc (at least at the present moment ;)

Comment: Thanks! Please accept the answer as valid and provide a +1 if you find useful. This is not to feed my ego ;) but to show other SOF users that the answer is correct.